# Is there something wrong with this counterpoint practice?

Tags: counterpoint, species-counterpoint

[image]

I've been studying 16 century counterpoint through a book myself.

I just got into 3 voice 3 species and its a little confusing.

This is a part of a 16 centrury counterpoint practice I did.

I'll like some feedback and pointers on anything "wrong" if I've broken any rules.

Thank you.

Comment: Hm, second measure is not optimal. You have the bass starting on c in the first measure and on d on the second measure. This will have up to a bit of diminuition the effect of soprano and bass going in parallel octaves.

Comment: Curious - can you please provide a translation into English of what you wrote in Korean in Bar 2?

Comment: Also, in second measure depending on how closely you're following 16th century style, leaping up from the strong beat is best avoided

Answer (score 2):

As @nuggethead pointed out you have somewhat parallel motion between the first notes in the bass and soprano.
A slight improvement would be to change the soprano to A in the second measure.

1. It gives a full triad.
2. It changes the perceived parallel motion to contrary motion.

In an exercise this short, you really want to avoid repeated harmonies.
Measure 1 is primarily C major and so is measure 3.
Consider changing the soprano, which is repeating the note from measure one to another note, and another harmony.
G major, A minor, F major or even Bb major (assuming mixolydian mode) would all break up the monotony.